# Semantic segmentation with already present instance segmentation coordinates

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library, object-detection, semantic-segmentation

I am trying to do Object detection. Initially I did instance segmentation from labeling tools and got the coordinates of the segmented classes. Now, I am trying to do semantic segmentation.

1. Instead of labelling again, I want to use the coordinates that I already have to label the classes and
2. I want to get the unlabeled pixels and label it something. How can I do this using python? I know I can access the pixels of the image using PIL or numpy etc but I am not able to understand how to access the unlabeled pixels and how to label them.

My present coordinates are in coco format:

```
{"id": 1, "image_id": 0, "category_id": 5, "bbox": [1955, 1999, 625, 623], "area": 389375, "segmentation": [[2483, 2009, 2408, 2012, 2305, 2024, 2243, 2032, 2203, 2042, 2181, 2075, 2183, 2091, 2200, 2125, 2200, 2136, 2195, 2140, 2164, 2146, 2148, 2157, 2134, 2180, 2132, 2191, 2139, 2199, 2157, 2197, 2154, 2207, 2134, 2239, 2123, 2248, 2098, 2250, 2082, 2258, 2067, 2282, 2066, 2291, 2072, 2296, 2090, 2296, 2091, 2301, 2073, 2327, 2055, 2342, 1982, 2348, 1969, 2360, 1964, 2384, 1976, 2422, 1960, 2440, 1955, 2460, 1977, 2486, 1974, 2505, 1976, 2532, 1981, 2536, 2061, 2531, 2089, 2536, 2147, 2537, 2170, 2544, 2193, 2559, 2231, 2548, 2280, 2544, 2291, 2550, 2292, 2564, 2311, 2608, 2323, 2622, 2332, 2618, 2351, 2588, 2372, 2510, 2388, 2481, 2394, 2457, 2467, 2270, 2503, 2209, 2578, 2016, 2580, 2004, 2576, 2000, 2541, 1999, 2483, 2009]], "iscrowd": 0}
```

Comment: Please click [edit] and add your [mcve] and images. Thank you.